# Unable to add custom validation rules using client side validation module in Drupal 7

Tags: forms

First I want to clarify that I am new to Drupal. So please excuse me If my question is naive.

I have installed the `Client Side module` in Drupal and it is working fine for all the required fields. I have built a custom form using Drupal form API. Now I want to add some custom rules to some of the fields on the from. I have searched on the internet and found this https://drupal.org/project/fapi_validation and below is the code that I have implemented but this is not working. I think there is some thing that I am missing here.
The module name is **instructor_registration** and I have written this code in instructor_registration.module file.

```
function instructor_registration_fapi_validation_rules() {

return array(
    'select_required' => array(
        'callback' => 'validation_rule_select_required',
        'error_msg' => 'Please select %field',
    ),
);
}

function validation_rule_select_required($value) {
if ($value == '0') {
    return FALSE;
}
else {
    return TRUE;
}
}
```

In the form element I am calling this as :

```
'#rules' => array('select_required'),
```

If there is any other information required from my side then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Actually the code that I was writing was not complete. The examples for adding custom rules in client side validation can found at https://drupal.org/node/1324772 . Hope this helps some one.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code... I found the tutorial a bit difficult to follow...

Comment: Sorry but I don't have the code.

Comment: Successfully I've created a custom rule :)

Comment: That is good to hear. Cheers